# While loop breaks early

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, vector, while-loop

I've made a program that asks for student information (name, course and grade) and it is configured to break whenever the input name of a course or a student is `stop`

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<string> v;
    string name;
    string course;
    string grade;

    while (name != "stop") {
        cout << "Please type a student name: ";
        getline(cin, name);

        if (name != "stop") {
            v.push_back(name);
        }

        while (course != "stop") {
            cout << "Please type a course name: ";
            getline(cin, course);
            if (course != "stop") {
                v.push_back(course);
            }
            if(course != "stop" == 0){
                break;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Please type the grade: ";
                getline(cin, grade);
                v.push_back(grade);
            }
        }
    }



    //for (auto iter = v.begin(); iter != std::prev(v.end()); ++iter){
    //    std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    //}

    return 0;
}
```

I want the program to ask for a new student whenever the first students course is called "stop", but that just means that whenever the new student name is typed, the while loop for "course" keeps "breaking" because the last course entered is "stop".

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Sorry if the question is elaborated badly, let me know if you need more clarification!

Thanks :)

Comment: You will have to reset the `course` after the while loop to keep your while loop as it is. [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear)

Comment: On a side note: `if(course != "stop" == 0)` should be `if(course == "stop")`. And I would suggest using `do..while` loops instead to eliminate the redundant string checks. And you should check `getline()` for failure, in case the user types Ctrl-C, for instance.

Comment: Good point with a do..while you don't need to reset because the user input is taken before the check.

Comment: Thanks guys ! :)

Comment: My [clean up](https://godbolt.org/z/h1zo697zh).

Comment: Thanks Marek R :D

Comment: By the way guys, any idea how I print all this? I need to print like this: " Student - Course - Grade"

Comment: For that you should ask a brand new question and show your attempted solution.

Comment: @drescherjm Okay, I'll try to fix it myself first

Comment: At StackOverflow we want to keep each topic separate because with the Q&A format the main purpose of a question is to help future readers solve the same 1 problem. When you mix in unrelated problems it may be more difficult for future readers to find the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this if statement

```
    if (name != "stop") {
```

should be enlarged and include the inner while loop that should be rewritten as a do while loop.

For example

```
while (name != "stop") {
    cout << "Please type a student name: ";
    getline(cin, name);

    if (name != "stop") {
        v.push_back(name);

        do
        {
            cout << "Please type a course name: ";
            getline(cin, course);

            if (course != "stop") {
                v.push_back(course);
                cout << "Please type the grade: ";
                getline(cin, grade);
                v.push_back(grade);
            }
        } while ( course != "stop" );
    }
}
```

Also as **@Remy Lebeau** wrote in a comment the outer while loop also can be rewritten as a do-while loop.

Comment: You may as well use a `do..while` for the outer loop, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the `course` variable to empty string `""` in the `if` where you break the inner while loop.

Like this:

```cpp
if(course == "stop") {
    course = "";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Prefer to use `course.clear();` instead of `course = "";`.

Comment: I would suggest clearing `course` before or after the inner loop, not inside of the loop.

Comment: this is unimportant, since next read sets new value for this variable.